# Plotting a directed graph with Dash through Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly-dash

It seems Dash is unable to process directed network graphs via plotly. So I am going through Matplotlib to render the graph using mpl_to_plotly. 
A graph does render on the site, but without the edges, and there is the following console output:

> Dang! That path collection is out of this world. I totally don't know
>   what to do with it yet! Plotly can only import path collections linked
>   to 'data' coordinates

Matplotlib code

```
mpl_fig , ax = plt.subplots()

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge('a', 'b', weight=0.6)
G.add_edge('a', 'c', weight=0.2)
G.add_edge('c', 'd', weight=0.1)
G.add_edge('c', 'e', weight=0.7)
G.add_edge('c', 'f', weight=0.9)
G.add_edge('a', 'd', weight=0.3)

elarge = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] > 0.5]
esmall = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] <= 0.5]

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # positions for all nodes

# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=700)

# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=elarge,
                       width=6)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=esmall,
                       width=6, alpha=0.5, edge_color='b', style='dashed')

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=20, font_family='sans-serif')


# error with plotly no supporting this kind of thing. Ty exporting to image and just show the image. Sucks becaues it is not interactive... but at least im showing what I want. 

print(pos)

#plt.show()

plotly_fig = mpl_to_plotly(mpl_fig)
```

called in Dash via

```
dcc.Graph(id='network-graph', figure=plotly_fig)
```

Is there another method to process network directed graphs in Dash? Or another way to use the matplotlib technique?

Comment: have you tried mpl_to_plotly(mpl_fig, resize=False, strip_style=False, verbose=False)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This gave the same result as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an opened issue in Plotly that `mpl_to_ploty` doesn't work with `draw_networkx_edges` ([link](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1566)).

Also Plotly doesn't natively support directed edges ([link](https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-add-arrowheads-to-edges-between-nodes-in-a-directed-network-diagram/9376)), they might be simulated with arrows from annotations though.

Given that graph figure might be constructed manually with Plotly syntax, e.g. as (without Matplotlib):

```
import networkx as nx
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge('a', 'b', weight=0.6)
G.add_edge('a', 'c', weight=0.2)
G.add_edge('c', 'd', weight=0.1)
G.add_edge('c', 'e', weight=0.7)
G.add_edge('c', 'f', weight=0.9)
G.add_edge('a', 'd', weight=0.3)

elarge = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] > 0.5]
esmall = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] <= 0.5]

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # positions for all nodes


Xn=[pos[k][0] for k in pos]
Yn=[pos[k][1] for k in pos]
labels = [k for k in pos]

nodes=dict(type='scatter',
           x=Xn, 
           y=Yn,
           mode='markers+text',
           marker=dict(size=28, color='rgb(31,120,180)'),
           textfont=dict(size=22, color='#DBD700'),
           text=labels,
           hoverinfo='text')

Xaxis=dict(showline=False, zeroline=False, showgrid=False, showticklabels=True,
          mirror='allticks', ticks='inside', ticklen=5, tickfont = dict(size=14),
          title='')

Yaxis=dict(showline=False, zeroline=False, showgrid=False, showticklabels=True,
          mirror='allticks', ticks='inside', ticklen=5, tickfont = dict(size=14), 
          title='')

annotateELarge = [ dict(showarrow=True, arrowsize=0.9, arrowwidth=6, arrowhead=5, standoff=14, startstandoff=4,
                         ax=pos[arrow[0]][0], ay=pos[arrow[0]][1], axref='x', ayref='y',
                         x=pos[arrow[1]][0], y=pos[arrow[1]][1], xref='x', yref='y'
                        ) for arrow in elarge]
annotateESmall = [ dict(showarrow=True, arrowsize=1.5, arrowwidth=2, arrowhead=5, opacity=0.5, standoff=14, startstandoff=4,
                        ax=pos[arrow[0]][0], ay=pos[arrow[0]][1], axref='x', ayref='y',
                        x=pos[arrow[1]][0], y=pos[arrow[1]][1], xref='x', yref='y'
                        ) for arrow in esmall]

layout=dict(width=800, height=600,
            showlegend=False,
            xaxis=Xaxis,
            yaxis=Yaxis,
            hovermode='closest',
            plot_bgcolor='#E5ECF6',
            annotations= annotateELarge + annotateESmall, #arrows
            )

plotly_fig = dict(data=[nodes], layout=layout)


#Dash page stub
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Graph(id='network-graph', figure=plotly_fig)
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```